# Kotlin Generics custom Type using Wildcard

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

So in Java I can do the following, to define a Type which has an Superclass and Interface constraint.

```
public class Main<ControllerType extends Node & Controller> {
    private ControllerType controller;
    private ControllerType controller2;

    private Main(ControllerType controller, ControllerType controller2) {
        this.controller = controller;
        this.controller2 = controller2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main<?> main = new Main<>(new Home(), new Parent());
    }
}
```

But in Kotlin this is not possible.

```
class Main<ControllerType>(val controller: ControllerType, val controller2: ControllerType)
        where ControllerType : Node, ControllerType : Controller

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val main = Main<*>(Home(), Parent())
}
```

I get the following error on the star projection:

> Projections are not allowed on type arguments of functions and properties

So how could one, solve this problem. I looked into type aliases but they don't have my desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do it as Java like wildcard. This is not possible because wildcard is **NOT** safe.

```
private Main(ControllerType controller, ControllerType controller2)
```

`controller` and `controller2` are suppose to be the same or inherited type but Java allow you to duck type it with wildcard.

Star projection is not a wildcard replacement. Star projection is you use when you do not know the exact type and allow you to perform safe operation.

If `controller` and `controller2` are two different type, then you should have two generic parameters.

```
class Main<T, U>(val controller: T, val controller2: U)
        where T : Node, T : Controller, U : Node, U : Controller

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val main = Main(Home(), Parent())
}
```

Comment: I think this use of wildcard is safe because `controller` and `controller2` do have a common type which satisfies the constraints: at least `Node & Controller`. Java only allows _writing_ intersection types in very few contexts and this isn't one of them, but they still exist and can be inferred.

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused solely by an attempt to use wildcard(projection) in an instance creation expression. It has nothing to do with intersection types or Kotlin.

In the statement

```
Main<?> main = new Main<>(new Home(), new Parent());
```

`<>` is NOT `<?>`, it is `<Node>`

in Kotlin the same statement would be

```
val main : Main<*> = Main<Node>(Home(), Parent())
```

or (without the explicit type argument)

```
val main : Main<*> = Main(Home(), Parent())
```